# タグWikiにはタグの読みがなを入れるべきか?

Tags: 討議, タグwiki

例:

> JavaScript（ジャヴァスクリプト）とは、プログラミング言語のひとつである。Javaと名前が似ているが、異なるプログラミング言語である。

[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1937)で修正される前の、JavaScriptのタグWiki抜粋です。

私見では

- タグWiki抜粋/要約には読みがなを入れない: タグの付け方を説明するのが目的なので、タグ自体の説明は本文に譲る
- タグWiki本文には入れてもよい: とくに、読み方がすぐには分からないようなタグは入れてよい

と思いますが、ルールをあいまいにしないために、「タグWikiの本文側には必ず読みがなを入れる」のを目指すのもありかなと思います。どうでしょうか。

Comment: 読み方が複数存在する場合に、どれを採用するかということも問題になると思います。

Comment: 日本語Wikipediaでは[読みがなを振る](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)ルールで統一しているようです。スタックオーバーフローでも真似る必要は無いとは考えますが一つの参考に。私個人としては、@h2so5 さんが指摘する通り表記揺らぎで揉めるリスクがあると思いますので、そのくらいならいっそ不要ではと考えています。

Comment: 発音記号ならまだしも、日本語として定着していない英単語のカタカナ表記は疑問に感じます。ヴァなのかバなのかとか、コンピュータなのかコンピューターなのかなど、結構統一されていないカタカタは多いと思います。

Answer (score 3):

**抜粋(要約)** に関してはポップアップ等で表示され文字数制限もあるので、まずは「タグの使い方の説明」を優先すべきで、読みがなは優先度が下がる(=記載は不要)と思います。

どうしても記載するのであれば、タグの本文に含めるべきでしょう。